# Equivalent SP in MySQL for sp_xml_preparedocument of SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, openxml

I have two queries -

1. What would be the equivalent sp\function name in MySQL for **`sp_xml_preparedocument`** of SQL Server?
2. What would be the equivalent sp\function name in MySQL for **`OPENXML`** of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, SQL Server itself has moved off sp_xml_preparedocument and openXML - these are procedural functions that use handles - very unwieldy.

In MySQL, you can use the XML functions ExtractValue and UpdateXML http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html

And here's a very short intro on how to use them http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-5.1-xml.html

Answer (score 1):

In sp_xml_preparedocument \ openXML, I can directly put my XML and can use as a table. But, in case of ExtractValue and UpdateXML, I have to insert each xml row in seperate row of the table and then select. Concedering the following example - 
if I want to use `'<books>
<book>
<title>A guide to the SQL standard</title>
<author>
<initial>CJ</initial>
<surname>Date</surname>
</author>
</book>
<book>
<title>SQL:1999</title>
<author>
<initial>J</initial>
<surname>Melton</surname>
</author>
</book>
</books>'`
This xml I can use directly in SQL Sql Server. But in case of MySQL, I have to insert two row into the table then use ExtractValue function.